# ListBox cannot scroll down to long ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I am working on WPF where I have a problem where if a `ListBoxItem` is very long, the `ListBox` cannot scroll until the end of the `ListBoxItem`. Below is the code:

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <TextBlock Text="abc"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <TextBlock Text="VerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylong123" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Notice that I put 123 at the end of the very long text, to see whether `ListBox` can scroll down to see the text. However, this is what I see when I scroll down:
[image]

What should I do to make it able to scroll even lower (to see the "123" at the end of the `TextBlock`")

Also, I would like to have the mouse wheel to be able to scroll when pointing to the `ListBoxItem` / `Text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to place your `ListBox` inside a `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <TextBlock Text="abc"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <TextBlock Text="VerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylong123" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Edit**:If you want to make your mouse wheel scroll add the `PreviewMouseWheel` event to your [`ScrollViewer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
<ScrollViewer PreviewMouseWheel="UIElement_OnPreviewMouseWheel">
```

And:

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewer scv = (ScrollViewer)sender;
    scv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scv.VerticalOffset - e.Delta);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, but how to make my mouse wheel scroll too when the mouse is pointing at the text?

Comment: @kurakura88 Just move the mouse over the scroll bar then wheel the mouse.

Comment: Well, I would like to be able to scroll when my mouse is pointing at the text, so... not the best option to me. But thanks!

Comment: I did not downvote. Someone did. Thanks for the update on the MouseWheel solution.

Comment: @kurakura88 I'm wondering how `CanContentScroll=false` is working? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it worked. You should give it a try too to see.

Comment: @kurakura88 I tried but didn't get any result. Am I missing your mean?

Comment: You don't wrap with ScrollViewer, but in ListBox you just add the ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False". This way, the mouse wheel is working without any code behind. So, I think his solution is much nicer to me. (Sorry, for not picking yours as the accepted answer)

Comment: @kurakura88 And what about the [**performance**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx) point of view?

Comment: Am I being tested right now? It was not my requirement. But, if people really suggest that the ScrollViewer wrapper is the better choice... then ok...

Comment: Is there a better way to implement long texts?, I have multiple long word pages of texts and reports that should be copied inside the application to show in different places in my application, so maybe there is a smart way to have the all the word documents or other kind of document type inside the application and then bind their content somehow to ListBox or Listblock, etc? so that it will be easier to edit the texts by the programmer if needed in the future, the user will not edit the texts but read only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

```
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"
```

but with the cost of Virtualization,
Setting CanContentScroll to false will disable the virtualization of ListBox which may cause performance problems. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx) - by Alex

Comment: Setting CanContentScroll to false will disable the virtualization of ListBox which may cause performance problems. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Alex is it possible to re-enable the UI virtualization by setting IsVirtualizing to true.

Comment: @kurakura88 No, you can't re-enable it by setting IsVirtualizing because ocne you set CanContentScroll to false you switch from scrolling per-item to scrolling per-pixel which does not support virtualization.

Comment: @kurakura88 BTW that is actually why this answer solves your initial problem in the first place.

Answer (score -2):

Wrap you `ListBox` inside a `ScrollViewer`

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="abc"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <TextBlock Text="VerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylongVerylong123" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: That did the trick, but how to make my mouse wheel scroll too when the mouse is pointing at the text?